# Datatable row.add([]) passing a jquery dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using dataTable and need to add a jquery dom to one column. The following is my code:

```
var markup = $("<a></a>").addClass("ClassName")
            .attr({ href : "Something.html",title : "Edit"});

var t = $("#myTable").DataTable();

t.row.add( [markup] ).draw( false );
```

The above code displays "[object Object]" in the column instead of the required href.

here is my table structure:

```
<table id="myTable" >
 <tbody> 
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing jquery object, try passing javascript object like this

```
t.row.add( [markup[0]] ).draw( false );
```

Because `row.add` description says this for dom objects

> Data to use for the new row. This may be an array, object, Javascript
>   object instance or a tr element.

Specially this part

> Javascript object

**Update**

I tried in all the way possible but it is not working in any way, seems a bug in `DataTables`, but there is a workaround that you can use, try adding your markup like this

```
t.row.add([markup.wrap('div').parent().html()]).draw(false);
```

or just put direct markup, like this

```
t.row.add(['<a class="ClassName" href="Something.html" title="Edit">Edit</a>']).draw(false);
```

**[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yza924ws/2/)**

Comment: Nope not working it displays the url which i have given in href

Comment: @user2713255 Please post your table structure as well.

Comment: Added table structure

Comment: @user2713255 - I have updated my answer for the workaround that you can try

Comment: Yup directly putting the markup works.

`t.row.add([markup.wrap('div').parent().html()]).draw(false);` this one does not work.

Thanks for your inputs

Comment: Did you check the fiddle? This is also working there `t.row.add([markup.wrap('div').parent().html()]).draw(false);` I have updated it, you can check the Fiddle. Anyways if the answers solves your problem you can mark the answer correct

Comment: Yes that one works too but in addition it also displays some text which I dont understand , like in my case "toggle navigation" was being displayed before the href dont know why.

Comment: Okay it worked when i did this:
`markup.wrap("<a>").parent().html();` Although i donot undestand why .parent() is needed or what is does

Comment: Because you want to get the html content of your element which is not directly possible, so you have to wrap it first inside another element and then have to get the html of that parent element.

Comment: Thanks . Some more solutions here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723480/coverting-jquery-dom-to-html/37723532#37723532]