# Coverting jquery DOM to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have the following jQuery DOM :

```
var markup = $("<a></a>").addClass("ClassName")
            .attr({ href : "Something.html",title : "Edit"});
```

I want to convert the above jQuery DOM(`markup` variable) to html . How to do the same?

Comment: If I understood correctly do you want this?<a href="somenthing.html" class="classname" title="Edit"></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either get **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** property of dom element

```js
var markup = $("<a></a>").addClass("ClassName")
  .attr({
    href: "Something.html",
    title: "Edit"
  });

console.log(
  markup[0].outerHTML
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Or wrap by an element and get html content using **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method.

```js
var markup = $("<a></a>").addClass("ClassName")
  .attr({
    href: "Something.html",
    title: "Edit"
  });

console.log(
  $('<div/>', {
    html: markup
  }).html()
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You just inverted your snippets order :) And just as a side note, imho it is more consistent to use `markup.prop('outerHTML')` but really doesn't matter here

Comment: The snippet for html wrapper is just below your statement to use outerHTML, and the opposite

Comment: Thanks the solution works  . But why do we need to specify index `[0]` ?

Comment: @user2713255 : to get dom element from jQuery object, `outerHTML` is a property of dom elemnt. also you can use `markup.prop('outerHTML')` as A.Wolf suggested

Answer (score 0):

To get the HTML you can `wrap()` it in another object, then retrieve the `html()` from that:

```
var $markup = $("<a></a>", {
    'class': 'ClassName',
    'href': 'Something.html',
    'title': 'Edit'
});
var html = $markup.wrap('<div />').parent().html();
```

Alternatively you can retrieve the `outerHTML` property of the underlying DOMElement:

```
var html = $markup[0].outerHTML;
```

Also just FYI, the term is a 'jQuery object'. There's only one DOM on the page.